# dict.get() returns None when key is from raw_input

Tags: dictionary, get, raw-input

Simply trying to get the value from the dictionary using the key as user input, but always returns a "None".

```
i= {x:(1 + 0.1)**x for x in list(range(1,21))}
print i
searchkey = raw_input("Enter no between 1 to 20:")
print(i.get(searchkey))
```

I just need to fetch the value for the key input.But this code always returns the default "None" even when the key exists.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

the raw_input() function returns string, try

```
 print(i.get(int(searchkey)))
```

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input